# AWS ALB endpoint returns 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have an interesting situation going on right now.

```
IF                                        THEN
Host is example.com                       Forward to:
Path is /abc?/*                           <load balancer URL1>

IF                                        THEN
Host is example.com                       Forward to:
Path is /*                                <load balancer URL1>
```

There are two target groups and both of them are healthy.
When I try to hit `example.com/abc1/something`-> this works with no issue. But, When I try to hit `<load balancer URL1>/abc1/something`-> this throws 404 error.

Q1: How does `example.com/abc1/something` is working if the load balancer is failing.

Q2: Few endpoints are just not working and returning 504 errors even though target groups are healthy.

Comment: Your rule is for `example.com`. Why would different domain work, including ALB domain in that case?

Comment: @Marcin I thought that if `example.com/abc1/something` works and `<alb-dns>/abc1/something` should also work [via postman] because I am just doing DNS mapping.

Comment: Your rule is based on `Host`. ALB has different host then the one in your rule.

Comment: @Marcin ok, any troubleshooting for Q2? I am not really sure since the target groups are healthy. `localhost:8082/abc1/something` works without any issue. So, I think it has to do something with infra but no idea why only one endpoint is failing while others are working just fine.

Comment: Not sure about question 2. I think you could make a dedicate question for that with relevant details. Its seems to be application specific. If you don't mind I will provide answer for Q1 based on your comments.

Comment: @Marcin Ok I guess.

Comment: This issue still persists?

Comment: @Marcin I fixed it. It was incorrect subnets.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments.

The `example.com/abc1/something` is working but default alb dns is failing, because the listener rules are set to respond to `Host` equal to `example.com`. However, default ALB dns has different host value, thus the given rule will not match ALB dns.

Comment: does the default alb DNS mean the DNS from AWS console?

Comment: @Amul123 yes. it does.